# Is there a way to combine models, LINQ to SQL classes and database diagrams?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm creating a lightweight database to rent movies.

I really like LINQ, so want to stick to that. My forms need validation so that is a requirement (ComponentModel.DataAnnotations).

Is there a model tool/template/thingy that combines them all, giving me the opportunity to create classes, generate them to the database (like the ADO.NET Entity Data Model), giving me LINQ (like LINQ to SQL Classes) and form validation (letting me implement ComponentModel.DataAnnotations)

Comment: asp.net mvc with entity framework code first meets all these requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use Entity Framework -  it supports all you need. Check [this ScottGu's article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) for more info.